# The function glMultiDrawElements does not work correctly

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to render a simple cube using the function 'glMultiDrawElements' (even if there is just one object!) but there is a bad display! However if I use the function 'glDrawElements' everything works! I want to precise 'glewInit' has been correctly initialized.

Here's the code using 'glDrawElements' :

```
[...]

std::vector<std::vector<int32_t>> indexArray = pRenderBatch->GetIndexAttribArray();
std::vector<int32_t> countArray = pRenderBatch->GetCountElementArray(indexArray);

// indexArray[0] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 0, 2, 19, 3, 5, 20, 21, 22, 10, 23, 11, 13, 24, 14, 25, 15, 17}
//Size(indexArray) = 1, Size(indexArray[0])=36
// countArray = {36} //Size(countArray)=1

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, countArray[0], GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (const GLvoid *)&indexArray[0][0]);

[...]
```

Now, here's the code using 'glMultiDrawElements' :

```
[...]

std::vector<std::vector<int32_t>> indexArray = pRenderBatch->GetIndexAttribArray();
std::vector<int32_t> countArray = pRenderBatch->GetCountElementArray(indexArray);

glMultiDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, &countArray[0], GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (const GLvoid **)&indexArray[0], countArray.size());

[...]
```

Here's the display:

[image]

However according the OpenGL documentation (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glMultiDrawElements.xml), the function 'glMultiDrawElements' has the following signature:

```
void glMultiDrawElements(GLenum mode, const GLsizei * count, GLenum type, const GLvoid ** indices, GLsizei primcount);
```

I don't understand why the display is not correct. Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int32_t>> indexArray
```

`glMultiDrawElements()` is expecting a pointer to an array of indexes.  It doesn't know anything about the layout of `std::vector<int32_t>`.

Try this instead:

```
std::vector< int32_t* > indexArray2
```

You can construct it like this:

```
std::vector< int32_t* > indexArray2( indexArray.size() );
for( size_t i = 0; i < indexArray.size(); ++i )
{
    indexArray2[i] = &indexArray[i][0];
}
```

**EDIT**: Complete example:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( -2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    GLfloat verts[] = 
    {
         0,  0,
         1,  0,
         1,  1,
         0,  0,
        -1,  0,
        -1, -1,
    };

    vector< GLsizei > counts;
    vector< vector< unsigned int > > indexes;
    {
        vector< unsigned int > index;
        index.push_back( 0 );
        index.push_back( 1 );
        index.push_back( 2 );
        counts.push_back( index.size() );
        indexes.push_back( index );
    }
    {
        vector< unsigned int > index;
        index.push_back( 3 );
        index.push_back( 4 );
        index.push_back( 5 );
        counts.push_back( index.size() );
        indexes.push_back( index );
    }

    vector< unsigned int* > indexes2( indexes.size() );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < indexes.size(); ++i )
    {
        indexes2[i] = &indexes[i][0];
    }

    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glVertexPointer( 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, verts );

    glMultiDrawElements
        (
        GL_TRIANGLES, 
        &counts[0], 
        GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 
        (const GLvoid **)&indexes2[0], 
        counts.size() 
        );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 600, 600 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glewInit();
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is an issue but it should only show up when trying to use more than one array of indices I think. Is it the source of the problem here ?

Comment: There's no guarantee that the first batch of bytes of the first `std::vector<int32_t>` is a pointer to an array of `int32_t`s.

Comment: True, there is no guarantee. But ain't the first member of std::vector the pointer to the array ? Don't misunderstand me, your answer is totally legit and solve a problem that would have show up later if it doesn't already solve the current problem also. I just wonder : if the first bytes are actually the ones of the array's pointer, shouldn't it work ? It does look like half the triangles have a wrong culling. The fact that a shift in the indices exists would be an possibility, that your answer solve.

Comment: @agrum: Yep, you're right, the first `vector` member is a pointer-to-`T`, at least for Microsoft's STL implementation.  But there are two more members after that so the *stride* between each pointer-to-`T` is non-zero.  Which is a problem because OpenGL is assuming the next index pointer is right after previous one.

Comment: Which will be a problem only if he tries to draw from more than one set of indices. The first set should be valid.

Comment: @agrum: Ah, I see what you're getting at now.

Comment: The problem is somewhere else. I mean you dug up a serious one, but it's not the one of this question. It looks like a culling. Plus the indices are really weird, they go from 0 to 24, why would a cube have 25 different vertices ? 8 OK, 24 OK, but 25 ?

Comment: Thanks Genpfault for this complete answer. It works and I understand why now. Now to respond to Agrum, I use .obj wavefront format to load my meshes. Effectively if I load a cube with just position vertices I'll have less indices. But Here I use texture and normal vertices too. So for the same vertex I'll have 3 different normals vertices (one different for each face). So this is why I have a lot of vertices. Do you have an idea to reduce the number of indices ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want I can open a question for this topic.